# MYSQL: self written string-manipulation function returns unexpected result

Tags: mysql, string, function

I'm trying to implement a MYSQL function MY_LEFT_STR(STRING x,INT position) in such a way that

- MY_LEFT_STR('HELLO', 4) **=>** returns 'HELL' (same as internal LEFT function)
- MY_LEFT_STR('HELLO',-1) **=>** returns 'HELL'

---

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MY_LEFT_STR;
CREATE FUNCTION MY_LEFT_STR(
  in_str VARCHAR(255),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
  IF (pos < 0) THEN 
      RETURN LEFT(in_str,LENGTH(in_str) - pos);
  ELSE          
    RETURN LEFT(in_str,pos);  
  END IF;           
END;
```

---

the result is

```
select left_str('HELLO', 4)            as A
     , left_str('HELLO',-1)            as B
     , left('HELLO',length('HELLO')-1) as C
from dual

+-----+-----+-----+
| A   | B   | C   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|HELL |HELLO|HELL | 
+-----+-----+-----+
```

**QUESTION**  What is wrong with my function declaration? (Besides a generall lack of testing for bordercases like *MY_LEFT_STR('A',-4)* ...

---

**ANSWER**: so embarassing ... the answer lies in the double negative for pos=-1 in

```
RETURN LEFT(in_str,LENGTH(in_str) - pos);
```

this should be

```
RETURN LEFT(in_str,LENGTH(in_str) + pos);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a clue:  What's the result of `LENGTH(in_str) - (-1)`?

When `pos` is negative, then `LENGTH(in_str) - pos` yields a number *longer* than the length of the string.  So `LEFT()` is bound to return the whole string, because you're asking for more characters than the total length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
RETURN LEFT(in_str,LENGTH(in_str) - pos);
```

If `pos` is negative, won't LENGTH(in_str) - pos give you (for your example):

```
LENGTH(HELLO) - (-1) = 6?
```